# Is this an acceptable question for AE? "Why does the android documentation forbid devices with external thermometer sensors?"

Tags: discussion, questions

I have a question I'd like to ask, but I'm not sure if it fits within the Android Enthusiasts policy, so I thought I'd post the question here to see if it is acceptable to post on the actual site.

> There is a google documentation spec that defines what a device must
>   be capable of in order to be granted the use of "Android (TM)" for
>   compatibility.
>
> I noticed that in Section 7.3.7 that devices should not have a
>   thermometer, and if they do, it should only measure CPU temperature.
>   It is not allowed in any way to measure any other temperature (ex body
>   heat or ambient/room temperature).
>
> Is there a reason Google forbids thermometers? Would this type of
>   sensor be too inaccurate and thus bring the perceived quality of
>   Android down (likened to a neighborhood ordinance to keep all lawns
>   mowed)?"
>
> Referenced question that talks about the spec (but not why):
>   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985396/is-there-any-android-api-to-find-sense-room-temperature-programmatically-in-andr

Comment: From a link your linked SO question, support for an [Ambient Temperature Sensor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE) was added in API level 14 (Ice Cream Sandwich). Seems like it is supported, and isn't banned any more? So regardless of whether it would fit, the question seems redundant now?

Comment: As for the answer to your question, it's speculative, but I guess it is because there is a lost context here. The document the quote is taken from is a compatibility suite, in a section describing an API for getting the temperature of the device. It is probably meant to prevent manufacturer from abusing it for ambient temperature instead, which will create a compatibility nightmare (and possibly even damaging the device). In short, the documentation forbids the use of this particular API for reporting ambient temperature, not forbidding ambient temperature sensor in general.

Comment: @LieRyan That sounds very plausible. It makes much more sense that they would want the API to have a specific function, as opposed to what I thought (google dictating that Android smartphones must never ever have external thermometers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you should ask Google.  We can only help you with end-user questions, not speculate about Google's internal decisions.